# Looking for some good books/resources on understanding Bittorrent?

Tags: p2p, bittorrent

Looking for some good books or technical resources for a detailed understanding of how Bittorrent works?  It would probably involve books on Network programming, P2P programming, and other topics.

Comment: Edited to make the programming relation more apparent.  So to speak.

Answer (score 2):

The first place to look would probably be [BitTorrent.org](http://www.bittorrent.org/). It lists the standard specification as well as a lot of the extensions that have become de facto standards (most of which have been developed by µTorrent or Azereus).

A thorough guide can also be found [here](http://jonas.nitro.dk/bittorrent/bittorrent-rfc.html), though it might not be as up-to-date as the first link.

Keep in mind that most of the complexity with bittorrent relates to the client implementations, whereas the server ("tracker") is fairly trivial.

Comment: what are some of the issues related to client implementations? is there a place to read about this and what programming techniques are used to overcome these hurdles?